# Angular How to pass scope to view from service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, view, scope

i have global function in helper service.

```
this.displayModalWithInput = function ($scope, title, cotroller, functionCallback) {
        $scope.modalProperties = {
            modalTitle : title,
            modalController : cotroller,
            modalFunction : functionCallback
        };

        $('#myModal').modal();
    };
```

In my template i have standard Bootsrap modal window. Problem is if i'm trying to access to scope using:

```
{{modalProperties.modalTitle}}
```

Nothing is displayed.

How can in solve it, if i want to use global available function and pass data from this global function into accessible scope?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Services (factories) are singletons and its not good practice (*I would say you can't*) to inject scope to service.

---

In your case to avoid code duplicate I would create directive instead (isolate scope) where in *link* function you can write all relevant logic.

This Demo might help you <kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/8hblhSasFI6yCUDH6y3l?p=preview)**</kbd>

*Directive Example*

```
.directive( 'confirmPopup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&', func: '&' },
    templateUrl: 'confirmPopup.html',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.confirm = function(){

        $scope.$parent.deleteThing();
        $scope.$parent.tt_isOpen = false;
      }
      $scope.cancel = function(){
        $scope.$parent.tt_isOpen = false;
      }
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

first define $scope.modalProperties=[]; in your controller.
Then, when you call displayModalwithInput function from controller, there please pass $scope as one of arguments. e.g. displayModalwithInput($scope, ...)
if it doesn't work, i'd like to see your global  service code.